# Efficient way to load a 3D vector into the lower three values of an AVX register

Tags: c++, c, sse, avx

Assuming proper alignment, what would be the most efficient way to load a 3D vector into an AVX register `__m256d`. For instance, for SSE we can do something like this

```
float __attribute__((aligned(0x20))) vector[3] = {1.f,2.f,3.f};
__m128i xy = _mm_loadl_epi64((const __m128i*)value);
__m128 z = _mm_load_ss(&value[2]);
__m128 vec = _mm_movelh_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(xy), z); // gives [1.f,2.f,3.f,0.f]
```

Now I wonder what would be the equivalent version given a `double vector[3]` and a `__m256d` register.

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't be opposed to the idea, but I want to make the code at least `AVX` portable.

Comment: Actually, I didn't notice that your vector is aligned in memory. So you could just do a regular load, getting some arbitrary value in 4th position, without risk of accessing a different memory page.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yes, but what if the vector/array had more than three elements and one wanted to load only three values into the register? The technique you mentioned would fail, unless the last element is zeroed out.

Comment: What does "load only 3 values" mean? If you really want a 0 as 4th value (as opposed to whatever arbitrary value you don't care about), that wasn't part of your requirements, you should have stated it clearly in your question.

Comment: I think that `_mm256_maskload_pd (double const * a, __m256i mask)` with `mask=_mm256_set_epi64x(0,-1,-1,-1)` is what you are looking for. This works also for unaligned addresses.